# Find the columns where a shape is located in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have two shapes in worksheet("Sheet1"). First shape is located from range A1 to D5 and second is from E6 to G10.

Regardless of the height, I want the columns in which the shapes are located (length of the shape).

In the example, the length of the shapes are A to D and E to G.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.topleftcell

Comment: What do you mean by *capture the column the shapes are located*? Did you mean columns (plural)? How should the result be presented, e.g. as a string "A:D", as a number 4? What would be the name of the function?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
What do you mean by capture the column the shapes are located? Did you mean columns (plural)?  > yes

How should the result be presented, e.g. as a string "A:D", as a number 4? >> string

What would be the name of the function? > not sure what you mean, just a simple sample code will do.

Answer (score 0):

### Shape-Occupied Columns Address

```vb
Option Explicit

Function ShapeLen(ByVal shp As Shape) As String
    ShapeLen = Split(shp.TopLeftCell.Address, "$")(1) _
            & ":" & Split(shp.BottomRightCell.Address, "$")(1)
End Function

Sub ShapeLenTEST()
    Debug.Print ShapeLen(Sheet1.Shapes("Rectangle 1"))
    Debug.Print ShapeLen(Sheet1.Shapes("Oval 2"))
End Sub

Sub ShapeLenTESTLoop()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.ID, shp.Name, ShapeLen(shp)
    Next shp
End Sub
```